# How to change legend's font types in corroplot-R

Tags: r

I am trying to change legend's font types in corroplot, please see my code!

```
library(corrplot)
windowsFonts(TNM = windowsFont("Times New Roman"))
#> corrplot 0.84 loaded
M <- cor(mtcars)[1:5,1:5]
colnames(M) <- c("alpha", "beta", ":alpha+beta", ":Ca^'2+'", ":a^2")
rownames(M) <- c("alpha", "beta", NA, "$a[0]", "$ a[beta]")
corrplot(M,type = "upper",order = "original",tl.col = "black",tl.srt = 45,family="TNM",tl.cex=2,cl.cex = 1.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `family = "serif"`. See code below.

```
library(corrplot)
#> corrplot 0.84 loaded
M <- cor(mtcars)[1:5,1:5]
colnames(M) <- c("alpha", "beta", ":alpha+beta", ":Ca^'2+'", ":a^2")
rownames(M) <- c("alpha", "beta", NA, "$a[0]", "$ a[beta]")
corrplot(M,type = "upper",order = "original",tl.col = "black",tl.srt = 45,family="serif",tl.cex=2,cl.cex = 1.5)
```

Comment: It seems only changed font type in matrix figure, i want to change font type of number in color index.